# How to link dynamically generated pages in MIddleman?

Tags: ruby, hyperlink, dynamically-generated, middleman

I am generating my dynamic pages with the following in `config.rb`

```
data.generated.each do |i|
  proxy "#{i.id}.html", "/generated/template.html", :locals => { :i => i }, :ignore => true
end
```

and a template in `source/generated/template.html.erb`

```
<% i = locals[:i] %>
<h1><%= i.title %></h1>
```

How can I create links to next and previous of these generated pages dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to generate all pages save for the first and last ones:

```
data.generated.each_cons(3) do |prev, curr, nxt|
  proxy "#{curr.id}.html",
        "/generated/template.html",
        locals: { prev: prev, curr: curr, next: nxt },
        ignore: true
end
```

The above would start with `curr` being the second page. I can’t find the quick solution to handle these corner cases in an elegant manner, so we’d just produce these pages manually:

```
def generate_page prev, curr, nxt
  proxy "#{curr.id}.html",
        "/generated/template.html",
        locals: { prev: prev, curr: curr, next: nxt },
        ignore: true
end

data_generated = data.generated
data_generated.each_cons(3).with_index do |(prev, curr, nxt), idx|
  generate_page(nil, prev, curr) if idx == 0
  generate_page(prev, curr, nxt)
  generate_page(curr, nxt, nil) if idx == data_generated.size
end
```

---

```
<% prev, curr, nxt = locals.values_at(*%i|prev curr next|) %>
<h1><%= curr.title %></h1>

  <a href="<%= prev.id %>.html">⇐ <%= prev.title %></a> |
  <a href="<%= nxt.id %>.html"><%= nxt.title %> ⇒</a>
```

It might be needed to apply the additional check for `nxt`/`prev` not being `nil` is required around building links.

Comment: Great idea! But I have problem with getting it to work with `[nil]`'s. Without them it works fine, except for the first page as you write. When I use the above example I'm getting: can't convert Middleman::CoreExtensions::Collections::LazyCollectorStep to Array (Middleman::CoreExtensions::Collections::LazyCollectorStep#to_ary gives Middleman::CoreExtensions::Collections::LazyCollectorStep) (TypeError)

Comment: Ah. Calling `to_a` on `data.generated` should help. Could you please check since I have no middleman here.

Comment: OK, I have suggested another hack :)

Comment: `next`is reserved word in Ruby

Comment: Indeed! What a stupid parser/language. I have updated the answer. Does it work with `with_index` btw?

Comment: Still no luck. No errors though, now it displays loading message and sits and waits.

Comment: I give up, sorry. `each_cons` looked very promising, but it turned out it brings more pain than profit.